# why i am having an attribute error in django

Tags: python, django, object, attributeerror

I'm beginner in django and studying it recently from a course, i'm working on authentication and login and logout functionality here is my Error 
[image]

And here is my views.py file

```
def user_login(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user:
        if user.is_ative:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")
    else:
        print("Someone tried to login and failed")
        print('Username:{} and password {}'.format(username, password))
        return HttpResponse("INVALID LOGIN DETAILS SUPPLIED")
else:
    return render(request, 'basic_app/login.html', {})
```

And here is my login.html file

```
{% extends 'basic_app/base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class = 'jumbotron'>
<h1>Please Login</h1>
<form action="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo in your code:

```
if user.is_ative:
```

Should be:

```
if user.is_active:
```

Comment: it solved.thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @wasif! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it and accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Cheers!

Comment: This should just be a comment and a flag/vote to close as it is a typo that is unlikely to help future readers.